# Unable to install spark in mac

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6

I used python 3.6 in macbook with installed java, and I downloaded spark 2.3.1 but spark cannot successfully be installed. BTW, I successfully used pip3 install pyspark. I have no idea what's going on!!
I attached my bash_profile and my errors on the terminal !

In bash_profile

```
        export java_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/HOme/"
        export SPARK_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark"
        export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH
        export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

On the terminal, it showed that

```
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pyspark: line 24: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pyspark: line 77: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you paste echo $SPARK_HOME value before running pyspark. It seems some issue with SPARK_HOME is not coming from bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate whether you have spark files at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark
you should have following folders under this:
LICENSE     R       RELEASE     conf        examples    kubernetes  python      yarn
NOTICE      README.md   bin     data        jars        licenses    sbin

if not download spark package and extract to some X directory. If extracted folder name is Y then set SPARK_HOME as till directory Y.
In my case it is something like this : /Users/rs1223/spark_package/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7

After this retry running pyspark. It should work.